# select the most accurate entry that is not created in error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to select the most recent correct case of a client, but I also need to be able to select any previous cases the client had. I have my query but when I was going through the data, I noticed that one client had 3 cases:

| CLIENT ID | CASE ID | CASE STATUS | CASE CREATED Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10079 | 2796 | Open | Jan 11, 2021 |
| 10079 | 2784 | Active | Jan 09, 2021 |
| 10079 | 1867 | Closed | Jan 29, 2020 |

I need to be able to select both the client's "**Closed**" and "**Active**" case. The "*Open*" case is an error and should not exist in the system since a client with an "Active" case cannot also have an "Open" case. There are a few instance like that in the database for different clients, I was wondering, can anyone please help me figure out how I can use sql to control for those system errors in a oracle database?
Please note: not all "Open" cases are system errors: a client cannot have an "Active" and "Open" case as the same time.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps a `where not exists(...)` might help filter out the situations where an Open case exists alongside an Active one.

Comment: I think your question needs more sample data -- what to include and not incude.

Comment: @IronMan, do you know how I can do that? Especially since I am worried that if I use a where clause, it will deselect clients that have an "Open" assessment which is completely valid and not a system error

Answer (score 0):

If you only want "opens" when the preceding status is not "active" (one way of reading your question, then you can use `lag()` and some filtering logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(case_status) over (partition by client_id order by created_date) as prev_case_status
      from t
     ) t
where status <> 'open' or
      (prev_status is null or prev_status <> 'active')
```

Comment: Hello, appreciate the query you have above :) Just wondering, if I were to apply this query to the client I have above, will it only give me their "Active" and "Close" case, and not the "Open" case (which is an error)? I am trying to not have the "Open" case show up in my final result